# How to make use of the internal functions?

Tags: powershell, dbatools

Basically we want to store backups on Azure Blob storage, yet `Invoke-DbaDbLogShipping` requires a `$BackupNetworkPath`. The closest I was to this was Azure File Shares but unfortunately port 445 is blocked it seems so I can't utilize that.

I'm now trying to modify the [Invoke-DbaDbLogShipping](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/1.0.52/Content/functions%5CInvoke-DbaDbLogShipping.ps1) function to replace the mandatory `$BackupNetworkPath` with Azure Blob Storage upload backups logic but I'm running into some issues:

```
Write-Message : The term 'Write-Message' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Test-FunctionInterrupt : The term 'Test-FunctionInterrupt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Stop-Function : The term 'Stop-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
The property 'StatementTimeout' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

To circumvent these errors, I copied/pasted the functions from the dbatools internal helper functions:

[Write-Message](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.9.209/Content/internal%5Cfunctions%5CWrite-Message.ps1)

[Stop-Function](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.8.933/Content/internal%5CStop-Function.ps1)

but I ran into yet another issue with `[Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.dbaSystem...]`

For example: `Unable to find type [Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.dbaSystem.MessageLevel].`

I tried importing the module `Import-Module dbatools` in the script before the `Invoke-DbaDbLogShipping` and that didn't help.

Comment: "Im now trying to modify the Invoke-DbaDbLogShipping function" - by modifying the containing module file (`allcommands.ps1`) in place, or by copying the function definition elsewhere and modifying it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen by copying the function definition elsewhere and modifying it. Wait where's the allcommands.ps1? Does it contain all dbatools functions which would resolve the problems including assembly references?

Comment: When you copy it somewhere else, it'll no longer inherit it's _scope_ from the `dbatools` module and you'll no longer be able to resolve any private scoped functions belonging to the module. You'll want to edit the function definition _in place_ instead. Although the best option is probably to open an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/issues) and request this feature - the dbatools community is usually pretty responsive :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh I see, makes sense. Where do I edit it in place? Is it the allcommands.ps1 file? Can you link it to me please? Also I did consider posting a feature request but we have to deliver a log shipping solution in like 2 weeks, which I dont think will be enough time for the community to resolve

Comment: If I install the latest version of `dbatools` from the gallery, the file is in the root folder, you should be able to resolve the path with `Get-Module -ListAvailable dbatools |Split-Path -LiteralPath {$_.Path} |Join-Path -ChildPath allcommands.ps1`